# Distributing R scripts that use external packages

Tags: r, scripting

I am working within a small group of mostly non-technical users and would like to distribute an R script within the group. This uses 'RScript' in the shebang line, takes some command line arguments and produces a graphics file and some text as output.

I am wondering if there are ways to ensure that any external packages that the script uses (even something like optparse for parsing arguments) is available to the user. I expect that everyone in the group will be able to invoke the program from the command line by following instructions but asking people to start R and download and install dependencies might be too much. I've used py2exe or py2app for similar situations in Python, but I am wondering if there are equivalent ways or at least best practices for distributing R scripts.

Comment: when you say 'libraries' do you mean 'packages'?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the fuzzy terminology.

Answer (score 10):

Create a package, declare the dependencies as Depends: in DESCRIPTION.  That works, and is tested widely across OSs.

You can then also place the package in a local repository, making updates easier and possibly even automatic. I once wrote a company-internal package which in its own startup code checked if a newer version was available on the local repository.

Answer (score 7):

Dirk's given you the best practice solution (packages with dependencies) but the next-best-practice solution is probably to use require(foo) and test if the package is there, and then get it if not. Something like:

```
if(require(foo)){
 # foo loaded okay
 cat("we got foo\n")
}else{
 cat("uh oh, no foo. let's get it\n")
 install.packages("foo")
}
```

you might want to specify a CRAN repo in install.packages so the user isn't interrogated, and also to use some options on require to stop warnings.

Comment: Good answer.  Also, along with Dirk's suggestion, one can specify a local repository / server, so that it is unnecessary to access CRAN.  If a local server is used, the admin can specify an automatic update of the internally derived package or suite of packages, to ensure consistency across installations.  Having users with different versions of packages can be a bit of a nightmare if one crashes or if there's not good testing of how everything should behave.